# Clicking on the latest date link using Python+Selenium giving me none object

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

My aim is to click on the first link(latest by date) of a 'FIXED INCOME SECURITIES' tab on a website. For this, I am trying with below code-

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('https://www.fbil.org.in/#/home');
browser.find_element_by_id('content-C').click()
link=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Gsec"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/a')
link.click()

browser.quit()
```

With the above code, I am able to click on the 'FIXED INCOME SECURITIES' tab and links are showing under GSEC tab. But code is not further moving to click on the first link (by latest date).

Can anybody please help me to find out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I think you are doing great, commenting the browser.quit(), you will actually see that the excel has been downloaded

Comment: are you want to click 24 Aug 2020?

Comment: Thanks @slackingslacker. I commented the quite() and able to download the file. So the link is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you click on the first link(latest by date) of a 'FIXED INCOME SECURITIES' tab on a website, there will be a task to download an Excel file. Then the `webdriver` shutdown the browser at `browser.quit()`, however, the downloading task has not finished yet.

So, if you click the first link just for downloading files, you could add "wait" for it.